# Beautifulsoup Easiest way to get the content of a tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The problem is that The `contents` of a Beautifulsoup tag is a list not a string. Thus I have to use a for loop to get the content inside a tag. It is cumbersome. Is there a better way to do so?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = u'<li><span class="def">1. <span class="cat">cat</span>example<span class="ex">ex</span></span></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
div = soup.find("span", class_='def')
print div.contents
result = ''
for divcont in div.contents:
    result = result + unicode(divcont)
print result
```

Output:

```
[u'1. ', <span class="cat">cat</span>, u'example', <span class="ex">ex</span>]
1. <span class="cat">cat</span>example<span class="ex">ex</span>
```

The string `1. <span class="cat">cat</span>example<span class="ex">ex</span>` is what I want, but I need a simpler method to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = u'<li><span class="def">1. <span class="cat">cat</span>example<span class="ex">ex</span></span></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
div = soup.find("span", class_='def')
print(''.join(str(e) for e in div))
```

Comment: Err, it is the same `for` loop, just in one line.

Comment: Yup. What are you looking for?

Comment: Some solution without the cumbersome `for` loop. As you know, `for` loop is extremely time consuming. You better avoid it. Maybe I am looking for something like this: `div.contentstring`